# Does the expression "note the irony" make any sense?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The context is this:

> Everything to not overwhelm the player with the huge amounts — note the irony — of items that he has to manage.

Basically the expression "note the irony" is saying that those "huge amounts of items" are in fact not huge.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically it makes perfect sense and most native speakers would understand it completely.

However “— note the irony —“ removes any subtlety. Unless you mean it to appear like shouting the point, it might be better to leave that out.

First, though, please look again at the rest of that wording…

Sentences starting with “Everything to… ” must end with something like “…had been done” or “…is ready” or "was considered".

An “amount” can be “huge” yet even then, items are not counted by “amount” but by “number”.